# Move button randomly on screen android

Tags: android, button, move

I am new to android developement.I want to have a singlebutton on the screen that continuously move. When it touches the sides,it should bounce back.and when clicked opens activity. How do i do this? Any helpful links? Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have tried anything prior to asking the question? Please describe your effort.

Comment: Inspire [from here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/bouncing-a-ball-on-androids-canvas/1733).

Answer (score 1):

for moving button you need to use animation 
here is snipplet of it

```
TranslateAnimation  mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
                            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1f,
                            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.2f,
                            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
                            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f
                           );
                   mAnimation.setDuration(15000);
                   mAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
                   mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
                   mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                   mAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

                    LinearLayout alertlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.alertll);
                    alertlayout.startAnimation(mAnimation);
```

and for opening a new activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
StartActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining what the set repeat count does? And how will this be moving randomly? Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, will this bounce back?

Comment: now there are much more sophisticated libraries available... try using that